# Asp.Net Core RC2 timeout on upload

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

Working on file upload with somewhat large payload (800 MB) and server is timing out.

Using asp.net core RC2, mvc6 and Kestrel server on Windows (7 and 10) and cannot find where to set the session timeout.

I'm going nuts that I can't find it searching the web. How do you set the timeout?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into a similar problem and found out that apparently IISExpress (at least when used from Visual Studio) has a default 2 minute connection timeout after which it responds with 502 bad gateway. I could fix the problem by adding the attribute "connectionTimeout" with a suitable value to the element "webLimits" in .vs\config\applicationhost.config:

```
<webLimits connectionTimeout="00:10:00" />
```

Here is some more info on the webLimits element: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/weblimits

Update after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 1.0: There is a "requestTimeout" attribute on the aspNetCore element in the web.config. This attribute also has a default value of 2 minutes.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore 
      processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" 
      arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
      forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" 
      stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
      requestTimeout="00:10:00" /> <!-- <== -->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more attributes on aspNetCore see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module

Comment: Another way to set this is IIS Manager -> Configuration Editor, you can set this as global setting or for specific site (also there is few more timeouts for different things, if you need).